# Invoke self in callback in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have the following reducer:

```
export const changeListener = () => (dispatch) => {
  changeListenerManager.update((res) => {
    changeListener();
    dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE', payload: res });
  });
};
```

Which should invoke `changeListener();` function, right after it has been called back. However, as the response comes back from native bridge (bridge receives callback function, stores it, and when change happens, it uses it to notify the app), the function is not called at all - and there is no error. If I am trying to invoke the method from the callback (in debugger), I get information, that it is undefined. How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changeListener` is a *curried* function, so you need to pass the second needed argument, `dispatch`.

Example:

```
changeListener()(dispatch);
```

**Note**: The current logic seem to have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! It does have infinite loop - the changeListener identifies timezone change, which I can't imagine that will be changed so often :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `changeListener` in the "body" of your function you need to call it twice. Once without a dispatch, once with:

```
export const changeListener = () => (dispatch) => {
  changeListenerManager.update((res) => {
    changeListener()(dispatch);  // <--- CHANGE
    dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE', payload: res });
  });
};
```

You are using higher order functions.